# What are alternatives to saucelabs?

Tags: web-services, software-testing

My question is regarding a software-as-a-service like saucelabs/browserstack, with which I am able to perform remote GUI selenium tests on various OS and browsers.

I have local selenium tests available, and want to use this software-as-a-service to have the tests run on their infrastructure on different OS and browsers (for some monthly fee up to 200 €/$ per month).

I know of saucelabs and browserstack, which both, unfortunately, do now work with rather complex test cases involving things like login, iframe changes, new windows and alerts.

Any suggestions for such a software-as-a-service are appreciated...